# Having trouble with using AWK command

Tags: bash, macos, variables, awk

I have two files being compared. Looking for exact words

Spellingwords.txt = has 15 words, each word per line.

Userwords.txt = user input. one word at a time.

**Results**

Spellingwords.txt (on the left column)

Userwords.txt (on the right column)

```
water water
gas   gas
boy   BOY
```

What happens here, is that the result should be 0 - but it returns with 1. The word BOY counts as a miss spelled.

How can I accept that the word *BOY* is the same is *boy*?

Here is my current code.

```
wword="$(awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{if(!($0 in a))c++;}END{print c+0}' spellingwords.txt /tmp/userwords.txt)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tolower` function to compare words in a case-insensitive way:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)];next}{if(!(tolower($0) in a))c++;}END{print c+0}' Spellingwords.txt Userwords.txt
0
```

Comment: `tolower()` is available in all awks.

Answer (score 1):

here is a slight improvement if the words are matched line by line

```
awk 'tolower($1)!=tolower($2){c++} END{print c+0}' <(paste list1 list2)
```

Comment: Not using a hash is a significant upside when files are large.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `IGNORECASE` option if your `awk` is `GNU` or other type that includes this option -- [check this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html).

Another option would be to use `diff` (with case insensitivity option `-i`) instead of `awk`, if you can. For example, `diff -i file-1 file-2` outputs the lines in the files that differ (ignoring case), with carets showing which file each particular line belongs to. The `--side-by-side` option to `diff` outputs each compared file, line by line, in separate columns, with non-matching lines marked. `diff` also returns "0" as exit code when files have no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Make all words lower-case before comparing them to each other:

```
wword="$(awk '{w=tolower($0}} NR==FNR{a[w];next} !(w in a){c++} END{print c+0}' spellingwords.txt /tmp/userwords.txt)"
```